# PowerShell Get-Date not refreshing in for loop

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have the following code:

```
$date=  "{0:T}" -f (get-date)

for($i=1; $i -le 18000; $i++){
 if (Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -count 1 -quiet )
  {
    write-Host "Success"
   }
  else
   {
   Add-Content $LogFile "`r`n`r`n Ping Failed at at " $date " `r`n "
  }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

The problem is that my `$date` always stays static. This means when a ping fails, the time is always the same

Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Comment: And `$date` will be static till the end of time, since you are assigning it to a variable. One way is to include the first line of your code in the `if-else` loop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the `Get-Date` gets only executed once (you assign it to a variable, its is not part of the for loop). Solution: you have to put it within your for loop:

```
for($i=1; $i -le 18000; $i++){
 if (Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -count 1 -quiet )
  {
    write-Host "Success"
   }
  else
   {
   $date=  "{0:T}" -f (get-date)
   Add-Content $LogFile "`r`n`r`n Ping Failed at at " $date " `r`n "
  }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```